# misplaced choice

Tags: single-word-requests

Can a person, a candidate be a **misplaced** choice?

*Most citizens rejected the Council's misplaced choice.* (meaning they didn't accept the choice of a person)

I know misplaced often goes with trust, loyalty etc. Not sure if it can refer to a person as above?

Comment: You can't place a choice. As a direct result, you also can't misplace it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Would you not say that this could be used if the choice were not appropriate or correct in the circumstances? That is one of the definitions of misplaced, and the ability or lack thereof to apply something's antonym doesn't necessarily discount it.

Comment: @JohnClifford i think you got my comment backwards. As well as your answer. I could use any word at all any way I please. That is not what the question is asking about. The question is asking whether people actually use this particular word in this particular way. And the answer is that they do not.

Comment: @RegDwigнt shogun didn't ask "Do people use this in this particular way?" The question was "Can a person be a misplaced choice?" and my answer explains how they can be. Also I know it's not like it's a statistically significant number but the 500+ results on Google for "misplaced choice" indicate that at least *some* people use it that way. ;)

Comment: The question is asking for collocations. Prior to posting my initial comment I actually went to the corpora and actually checked the collocations that people actually use. Unlike Google, these do return statistically significant numbers. And the statistically significant number that they returned in this case was 0. Your answer is built upon ignoring two very basic facts: dictionaries follow usage, not the other way round; and synonyms cannot simply be used interchangeably. Applying your logic, we can justify saying a great many things that people do not actually say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, a choice can meet a certain definition of *misplaced*.

One of the main sub-definitions of the word misplaced is

> (of an emotion or action) directed towards a person or thing that does not deserve it
>
> *[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/misplaced)*

The choice of a candidate can certainly be described as not appropriate or correct, so this definition would support the usage in this context.

In addition, when considering synonyms of misplaced we have

> misguided, unwise, ill-advised, ill-judged, misconceived, ill-considered
>
> *[Collins English Thesaurus](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/misplaced)*

As you can apply these adjectives to a "choice", whether of a candidate or not, you can replace them with a synonym, of which misplaced is one.

Comment: Thank you. Probably I didn't state it clearly enough but I was actually thinking of it as a synonym for 'inappropriate choice'.

Comment: I took the bold step of voting this down, in my experience one would misplace loyalty, a chair, some comments but not a choice.

Comment: @user356866 I appreciate your perspective; I still think this is a valid usage, but you're entitled to your interpretation and free to downvote as you see fit. ^_^